# Styling actionBar action item button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I have this actionBar:

[image: actionBar]

How do I change the style of the MUTE button text so that it isn't bold and is smaller and is of a different color? Adding `android:actionMenuTextColor` to AppTheme has no effect. Defining `android:actionBarStyle` also has no effect, like it's being ignored! I've looked at every other answer I can find, nothing works!

These are the styles that produce the actionbar seen above:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_bgr</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activity_bgr</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/activity_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/small_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NewActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/test_pink</item>
</style>

<style name="NewActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/test_pink</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NewActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="NewActionBarTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/action_bar_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/test_yellow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you want NewActionBar to be your action bar style then you must declare its parent to something like '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'

Comment: have you tried adding your items without the "android: " in the name?

Comment: What type of errors?

Comment: Uh sorry, the error was because of a typo I made. Removing the `android:` bit works! You should write that up as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `Theme.AppCompat` you need to drop the `android:` in your items name. Also read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810059/android-actionbar-style-ignored-by-later-devices-using-appcompat-v7) and the resource linked in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:actionMenuTextAppearance` in your main theme. For example, you could set that to `@style/NewActionBarTitle`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/NewActionBarTitle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No effect. I think I tried that before, too. :( The problem is whatever I put in the styles `NewActionBar` and `NewActionBarTitle` has no effect, like those styles are empty.