# buttonStyle not working for 22.1.1

Tags: android, compatibility

I´m Using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1`

This attribute `android:buttonStyle` is not setting that style for every button, I need to set `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"` manually on each button.

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
   </style>
```

What do I need to do to set a general style for it?

Comment: What version did this work on last?

Comment: Yeah, you said that in your question. Did `buttonStyle` work previously?

Comment: remove "android:" prefix and try.

Comment: when should I use android: attribute name?

Comment: @Harry removing "android:" leads to: Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonStyle'. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 19):

Use buttonStyle insteadof android:buttonStyle in your theme

Comment: when should I use `android:` attribute name?

Comment: @danielgomezrico From appcompat v21+ you should drop them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26815521/479478

Comment: @LenaYan Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonStyle'. Which resource should be used here? As original question states android:buttonStyle doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @danielgomezrico answer but without having two style files:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- android:buttonStyle for v21+ and buttonStyle for the rest -->
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting background color with `colorButtonNormal` attribute and other style attributes with `buttonStyle`.

`values/style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color_primary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_color_primary_dark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_color_accent</item>
 </style>

 <style name="AppTheme.Base">
   <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color_accent</item>
   <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
 </style>

 <style name="Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color_white</item>
 </style>
```

`values-v21/style.xml`

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
  </style>
```

And then all the buttons have the background/text color I wanted without setting `style` on each one.