# Not able to customize the actionbar manually

Tags: android, android-actionbar

IDE used=Eclipse JUNO
API level=14
Device's OS=4.2.2 Jelly Bean

---

I've been trying to change the background color and text font and font color of my action bar by using XML file.
I referred to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) tutorial and tried it but I got a message "Unfortunately, MyAppName has been stopped"

The code I am using to change my background is:

res/values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#6845db</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

After that I changed my app theme in Manifest as:-

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

I am a beginner to Android development.

---

My error log cat is:-

```
05-12 14:48:33.866: E/hawaii.gralloc(1449): GRALLOC ALLOC flags 933
05-12 14:48:33.886: E/HAWAII_EGL(1449): abuffer = (480 800) (933)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.decode.timer/com.decode.timer.HomeScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at com.decode.timer.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:15)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127):     ... 11 more
05-12 14:48:34.657: E/hawaii.gralloc(1449): GRALLOC ALLOC flags 933
05-12 14:48:34.687: E/HAWAII_EGL(1449): abuffer = (480 235) (933)
05-12 14:48:34.867: E/android.os.Debug(1961): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
05-12 14:48:35.087: E/hawaii.gralloc(1449): GRALLOC ALLOC flags 10000b22
05-12 14:48:35.147: E/hawaii.gralloc(1449): GRALLOC ALLOC flags 10000b22
05-12 14:48:35.157: E/HAWAII_EGL(1449): abuffer = (480 800) (10000b22)
05-12 14:48:35.618: E/hawaii.gralloc(1449): GRALLOC ALLOC flags 933
05-12 14:48:35.638: E/HAWAII_EGL(1449): abuffer = (480 235) (933)
05-12 14:48:35.848: E/hawaii.gralloc(1449): GRALLOC ALLOC flags 933
05-12 14:48:35.858: E/HAWAII_EGL(1449): abuffer = (480 235) (933)
05-12 14:48:45.688: E/dalvikvm(7141): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
```

Comment: i think u r doing right but ur problem is you put ur style to values/themes  you should try in v14/style..it will work..because you api level is v14

Comment: okay i am trying that out @Tufan

Comment: still same results :( @Tufan

Comment: Would you leke to do something like this    String title=getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString();
  final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();  ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FE642E"));    
        abar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77591/discussion-between-tufan-and-priyank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LogCat might have just given you the answer

> 05-12 14:48:34.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7127): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

So you just need to change the parent of your theme like this

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">#6845db</item>
</style>
```

Also, this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810059/android-actionbar-style-ignored-by-later-devices-using-appcompat-v7) might help you understand why you dont need to add `android:` before an item name when using AppCompat

For your TitleTextAppearance you'd have to create a style with `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title` as the parent

```
<style name="MyTitleTextAppearance"
    parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then set it as your `titleTextStyle` in your `MyActionBar` style

```
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextAppearance</item>
```

Comment: yeah !!!! it worked
but can you also tell me how to customize the text color and text appearance of action bar??? @freddieptf