# Android theme not applied on API v19 after migration to android studio (but is applied on API v21)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

I recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio. Now my customized theme is not appied anymore to devices below API21. Not completely sure but I think I changed nothing in my styles while migrating.

What I have is:
(don't wonder about the duplicates, I have two user-selectable themes)

**themes.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99335a9d</item>
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewTheme</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxTheme</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/ToggleTheme</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99335a9d</item>
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewTheme</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxTheme</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonThemeDark</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/ToggleTheme</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogDark</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewTheme" parent="android:Widget.AutoCompleteTextView"></style>

<style name="CheckBoxTheme" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/theme_btn_check_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="RadioButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/theme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonThemeDark" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ImageButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/theme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItemTheme" parent="android:Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/theme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTheme">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_tab_indicator_holo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <!-- v14 <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> -->
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">180dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/theme_progress_horizontal_holo_light
    </item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">
        @drawable/theme_progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light
    </item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>

<style name="SeekBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">
        @drawable/theme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light
    </item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">
        @drawable/theme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light
    </item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/theme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ToggleTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_toggle_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewTheme" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/theme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItemTheme" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"></style>

<style name="SwitchStyle">
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/theme_switch_inner_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:track">@drawable/theme_switch_track_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Title</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Title</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="Title" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
</style>

<!-- used for enhanced list view-->
<style name="elv_fade_animation">
    <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/elv_popup_show</item>
    <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/elv_popup_hide</item>
</style>

<!--  custom progress dialog -->
<style name="CustomProgressDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView"></style>

<style name="CheckBoxTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/theme_btn_check_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="RadioButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/theme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonThemeDark" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ImageButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/theme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItemTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/theme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTheme">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_tab_indicator_holo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">180dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/theme_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/theme_progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>

<style name="SeekBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/theme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/theme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/theme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ToggleTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_btn_toggle_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/theme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItemTheme" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"></style>

<style name="SwitchStyle">
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/theme_switch_inner_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:track">@drawable/theme_switch_track_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Title</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Title</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="Title" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
</style>
```

The links to @drawable are actual drawables created with http://android-holo-colors.com
If you find anything else (bad style or sth.) let me know as well. I'm quite new to android.

Comment: In your themes.xml, have you tried removing the "android:" prefix in your items name and see if it works?

Comment: @freddieptf Worked! That was easy. Thanks a lot. I just wonder why it worked in Eclipse?

Comment: I can't say i know, maybe your themes weren't using parents from AppCompat in eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `Theme.AppCompat` you don't have to include the `android:` prefix in your items name. Also you can checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810059/android-actionbar-style-ignored-by-later-devices-using-appcompat-v7) question here and [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) if you want to read more about it

Comment: for some items (e.g. imagebuttonstyle) I have to.

Comment: Yeah i also noticed for some i actually had to add the android prefix. In my case it was my listViewStyle. Not sure why but i guess it's something i did wrong